# Cognos excel report name not showing based on page break while scheduling why?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11

While the report running directly:

[image]

While scheduling the report:

[image]

Cognos excel report name not showing based on page break while scheduling why?
If am running the report directly as excel the excel sheet names are coming based on the BU Code,
But I schedule the same report it is showing title as reportname_1 and _2,
How to fix this issue

If am running the report directly as excel the excel sheet names are coming based on the BU Code,
But I schedule the same report it is showing title as reportname_1 and _2,
How to fix this issue